# having hard time debugging deletion of head node in a circular linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, circular-list

I'm learning data structures and was practicing questions on circular linked list. So, i'm supposed to write a function which deletes the `head` node of a circular linked list, so i came up with this code -

```
void del_head(struct node** head, struct node** tail)
{
    struct node* new_head = (*head)->next;
    free(*head);
    *head = new_head;
    (*tail)->next = *head;
}
```

After debugging i found that the `tail` is not getting updated.

I'm having tough time trying to find the problem.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the tail is not getting updated". Provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the test log/results which you use to reach that conclusion. One problem with the code is that it doesn't correctly handle the case where the list contains a single element when the head is deleted (ie, head and tail are same).

Comment: This is a recipe for disaster if your list is truly circular. I.e. a single-node list will have *three* pointers all referencing the same node: the `head` pointer, the `tail` pointer, *and* the node's own `next` pointer (e.g. the node points to itself because the list is, after all, circular). Harboring that tidbit of insight, how does the above fall on its face?. Trust me on this. Paper, pencil, single-line boxes for pointers, double-line boxes for structures, and arrows denoting what points to what, will be highly illuminating when learning dynamic data structure management practices.

Comment: A circular single  linked list does not need a `head` pointer.  just a `tail`. The head is found with `tail->next`.

Answer (score 1):

> *After debugging i found that the `tail` is not getting updated.*

Your code will work perfectly fine for a circular list having more than `1` node and since you are deleting `head` node, so if the list will have more than `1` node, `tail` will be pointing to same node after `head` node deletion as it was pointing to a node before deletion.

Consider a case where the circular list has only one node:

```
      head---+      
             |
   tail----+ |
           | |
          ---------------
          | data | next |-------+
          ---------------       |
             |                  |
             +------------------+
```

`head`, `tail` and node `next` all are pointing to same node.
For this scenario, your code will end up accessing a deallocated memory.

You can do:

```
void del_head(struct Node** head, struct Node** tail) {

    // validate head and tail pointer
    if (!(head && *head)) {
        printf ("Invalid head pointer\n");
        return;
    }

    if (!(tail && *tail)) {
        printf ("Invalid tail pointer\n");
        return;
    }

    struct Node* x = *head;
    if (*tail == x) {
        // the circular list has only one node
        *head = *tail = NULL;
    } else {
        *head = (*tail)->next = x->next;
    }

    x->next = NULL;
    free(x);
}
```

Comment: Good error checking and interesting proactive scrubbing of `.next` pointer.  UV.  Could even zero the entire node: `memset(x, sizeof *x, 0);`